# query mysql join between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have 2 tables

```
Matricule   date             presence minutes
248         31/01/2017         500
248         01/02/2017         400
248         02/02/2017         300
```

second table:

```
matricule  date_effet      time_passed_project
248        31/01/2017             250
248        31/01/2017             250
248        01/02/2017             300
248        02/02/2017             150
248        02/02/2017             100
```

what i want is to extract is the the date when an employee worked on project less than his presence knowing that an employee can work in multiple project in one day or just one for exemple in this case the 31/01/2017 the  employee worked in 2 projects 250 and 250 the total is 500 like the first table but in the rest it's not the same as first table and this is the date i want to extract knowing that the user will select a range date for exemple in this case maybe date between 28/01/2017 and 02/02/2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in two steps.  First, aggregate the total time spent on each date (for each `matricule`) in the second table, as a subquery.  Then, join this subquery to the first table, and retain those records for which the time worked is less than the presence time, and for which the matching records also fall within a date range you specify.

```
SELECT t1.matricule, t1.date, t1.`presence minutes`
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT matricule, date_effet, SUM(time_passed_project) AS total_time
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY matricule, date_effet
) t2
    ON t1.matricule = t2.matricule AND
       t1.date      = t2.date_effet
WHERE t2.total_time < t1.`presence minutes` AND
      t1.date BETWEEN '2017-01-28' AND '2017-02-02'
```

The output of the above query using the sample data you gave was the following two dates:

```
01/02/2017
02/02/2017
```

As a side note, if you are really storing your dates as text, which is what the formatting suggests, you should seriously consider using a date type, such as `datetime`.  Doing so will make it much easier to work with your data.  Minus the `WHERE` clause, my query should even work with text dates.  You may have to replace the `WHERE` clause with the following if your dates really be text:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(t1.date, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '2017-01-28' AND '2017-02-02'
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: i'm using datetime i just wrote the exemple the wrong way my bad  ur solution worked for me fine thnxs for the quick responce